# Define value of a centroid

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I want to choose a clustering algorithm for which I can define the **value** of centroids (and not only the number of them).

Which algorithm should I look at?

My understanding of k-means is that I can specify 'K' (the number of centroids) but not the value itself.

Instead, I have a given number of centroids that I want to "test". Some of them will be indeed the actual centroid, whilst others will have only few to none values and therefore I will drop them.
However, I don't want to create new values for the centroids.

Comment: In K means you can have random values for centroids or you can set them manually. Base on the occasion, you can choose what to do. There are also other approaches for setting the value of centroids.

Comment: what would another approach be?

Comment: You can take random points as centroids, or you can consider the space to intersections of grids and find consider them as centroids. There are some approaches for finding centorids. I suggest you using Gaussian Mixture Models. They are more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give the means, then it's not clustering anymore.

The name-giving part of k-means is computing the *mean*.

Instead, you are doing **nearest neighbor classification**. Your predefined means are your "training" data.